# Загрузка json файла в angularjs

Tags: json, angularjs

Добрый вечер.
В Angularjs создаётся массив, и я его отображаю.

```
$scope.zagruzit = function () {
$scope.VoprosiDB={"year":"2014 новые","ekzamen":"Крок-1"};};
```

Делаю json файл с точно таким же содержимым и гружу его - не работает.
Делаю ещё одну переменную с таким же значением и присваиваю `$scope.VoprosiDB=$scope.Mydb;` - работает.

Так гружу json:

```
$.ajax({
                url:'/getdata',
                type:"GET",
                success:  function(data) {
                alert(data);// -Отображает джейсон файл

                $scope.VoprosiDB=data; // данные слетают и ничего нет
            }});
```

Что-то не пойму, чем мой джейсон с сервера отличается от этого.
Подскажите пожалуйста, что делать.
Спасибо.

---

**Обновление**

С $http вообще даже не грузит:

```
       $scope.zagruzit = function () {
            alert('22222'); //есть
    $http({method: 'GET', url: '/getdata'}).
        success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            alert(data);      //нет
            alert('1111111'); //нет
        }).
            error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    alert('33333');  //нет
            });
   };
```

Comment: Тем, что вы не понимаете, как работает dirty-check, просто используйте [$http][1].
[1]: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: С $http не грузит. Может что-то не так делаю?

Comment: Наверно, у вас консоль полна ошибок... разместите пример на jsbin.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорей всего, вы отдаете json с неправильным content-type и получаете его как нераспарсенную строку. Проверьте content-type - он должен быть **application/json**.

На счет $http - покажите весь код. У вас, скорей всего, просто нету $http.

И еще на заметку: используйте console.log вместо alert, тогда легче понять, что вы выводите - строку или обьект.

Comment: Спасибо.Да. Заработало.Обошлось без content-type. Было 2 ошибки. В самом начале было подписано
var Voprosi= function($scope){...}
А надо было var Voprosi= function($scope,$http){...}
И в джейсоне у меня только значение было в кавычках, а надо было и имя в кавычки.